# How could I continue to show the inequality?

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $g: [0, \pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $C^{\infty}$ function for which the following stands: 
$$g(0)=0 \ \ , \ \ g(\pi)=0$$

I have to show that $$\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx \leq \int_0^{\pi}(g'(x))^2dx$$ using Parseval's formula.

$$$$

I have done the following:

The Fourier series of $g$ is $$g \sim \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (a_k \cos (kx)+b_k \sin (kx)\right )$$ where $$a_0=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}g(x)dx \\ a_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}g(x)\cos (kx)dx \ \ , \ \ k=1, 2, \dots \\ b_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}g(x)\sin (kx)dx \ \ , \ \ k=1, 2, \dots $$

From Parseval's formula we have the following:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\left (\frac{a_0}{2}\right )^2dx+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (a_k^2\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2 (kx)dx+b_k^2\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2 (kx)dx\right )=\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx \\ \Rightarrow \int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx=\frac{a_0^2}{4}\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (a_k^2+b_k^2\right )$$

The Fourier series of $g'$ is $$g'\sim \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (kb_k\cos (kx)-ka_k\sin (kx)\right )$$

From Parseval's formula we have the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (k^2b_k^2\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2 (kx)dx+(-k)^2a_k^2\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2 (kx)dx\right )=\int_0^{\pi}(g'(x))^2dx \\ \Rightarrow \int_0^{\pi}(g'(x))^2dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (k^2b_k^2+k^2a_k^2\right )$$

Is this correct?? Or have I done something wrong at the application of Parseval's formula??

How could I continue to show the inequality $$\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx \leq \int_0^{\pi}(g'(x))^2dx$$ ??

$$$$

---

$$$$

**EDIT:**

When we have to show with the Parseval's formula an inequality in which case do we have to take an expansion of the function that is involved at the inequality??

Comment: Well, I have the impression that you integral of $g'^2$ could be negative. The reason is that that minus should not be there, since it gets squared with the coefficients. With that, your inequality becomes $\sum(k^2-1)(b_k^2+a_k^2)\geq\frac{a_0^2}{2}$, by carrying the LHS to the right except for the $a_0$ term, putting sums together and dividing both sides by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you show it holds regardless of the coefficients?

Comment: I edited my initial post... I changed the sign... Is it correct now?? @MickG

Comment: Yes, I think the post is now correct. As I said, if you carry the LHS sum over to the right and put it together with the one on the RHS and then divide by pi/2, you get an inequality which seems pretty obvious, but can you prove it? I'm not too sure I can…

Comment: @MickG I have the following idea:

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k^2-1)(b_k^2+a_k^2)\geq \frac{a_0^2}{2} \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k^2-1)(\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)\sin^2 (kx)dx+\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)\cos^2 (kx)dx)\geq \frac{\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx}{2} \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k^2-1)\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)(\sin^2(kx)+\cos^2(kx))dx\geq \frac{\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx}{2}\\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k^2-1)\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2 (x)dx \geq \frac{\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}g^2(x)dx}{2}\\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2(k^2-1) \geq 0 \text{ which is true.}$$

Comment: Is this correct?? @MickG

Comment: Wait a second. $b_k^2$ is $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ times the square of the integral, not the integral of the square. Same for $a_k^2$. The passages seem reversable, so if you can show the second line implies the first you are done. One thing: the last line should have $1$ on the right, not 0. You divide both sides by $\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^\pi g^2(x)\mathrm{d}x$ so it vanishes from the left and leaves $\frac12$ on the right, then multiply by two, leaving 1 on the right and an extra 2 in the sum.

Comment: @Benjamin What do you think is missing ?

Comment: @Benjamin $sin(0) + 1 \neq 0$

Comment: anyhow why you say that the series of $g'$ is that one? I am pretty sure that in general you can't derive term by term the fourier coefficients, you need to make sure other properties hold.

Comment: @Ant I thought I have deleted my comment.  My apology. It's not a counter example.

Comment: The trick is to use the Fourier sine series.  Extend the function to [-$\pi$, $\pi$].  Then you wont' have the constant term and just use the Parseval identies for g and g' .

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-) @Benjamin

Comment: Another way of proving this inequality would be to note that $1$ is the lowest eigenvalue of the self-adjoint realization of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in $L^2(0,\pi)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions. I know it does not use Parseval, but someone might have a use for this way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose g is absolutely continuous in $[0, \pi]$ and $g(0) = 0$.  Suppose further that  $g ‘$  is square integrable.   Take the half sine series of g, that is to say we extend g to an odd function G in $[ - \pi , \pi ]$.  Then  G is periodic, absolutely continuous of period $ 2 \pi $ and the derivative $ G’ $ is Lebesgue integrable and square integrable since $ g ‘$ is square integrable.
The next thing we need to use is the relation between the Fourier coefficients of  $G$ and the Fourier coefficients of $ G ‘$.
If   *(0,  b<sub>n</sub> )*  is the Fourier series of  $ G $ , then  *(  n b<sub>n</sub> , 0)* is the Fourier coefficients of $ G’ $.   More precisely the formal derived series of the Fourier series of G is the Fourier series of $ G ‘$. 
Now we can invoke Parseval Theorem, since $ G $ and $ G’ $ are square integrable, to get:

$\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{G^2}(x)dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {b_n^2} } $ and

$\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{(G'(x))}^2}dx}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{n^2}b_n^2} $.

Therefore,

$\frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {{g^2}(x)dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {b_n^2} }  \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{n^2}b_n^2}  = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{(G')}^2}(x)dx}  = \frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {{{(g')}^2}(x)dx} $

and 
$\int_0^\pi  {{g^2}(x)dx}  \le \int_0^\pi  {{{(g'(x))}^2}dx} .$

The key to this problem is square integrability and the condition to extend to a continuous periodic odd function. g being absolutely continuous means that its derived function is Lebesgue integrable but may not be square integrable so we make the assumption that $ g' $ is square integrable. If g is smooth then both g and $g'$ are continuous and so are both square integrable. For the extension to odd continuous function we just need to have $g(0) = 0$.  We do not need to expand the function as a Fourier series.  We do not need to use the convergence of the Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G:[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$ G(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & \text{if } 0 \le x \le \pi \\
-g(-x) & \text{if } -\pi \le x < 0 \end{cases} $$
You can check that this function is continuous and differentiable (this is where the fact that $g(0) = 0$ is needed). Its derivative is given by
$$ G'(x) = \begin{cases} g'(x) & \text{if } 0 \le x \le \pi \\
g'(-x) & \text{if } -\pi \le x < 0 \end{cases} $$
Notice that $G'$ is continuous since $g$ is $C^\infty$.

Because $G$ is odd and $G'$ is even, their Fourier series have the following form :
\begin{align}
G &\sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \sin(kx) \\
G' &\sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k \cos(kx)
\end{align}
Using integration by parts and the fact that $G(\pi) = G(-\pi) = 0$, we can show that $A_k = k b_k$ :
\begin{align*}
A_k &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi G'(x)\cos(kx) \,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\left[ G(x)\cos(kx) \right]_{x=-\pi}^{x=\pi}
   - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi G(x)(-k\sin(kx)) \,dx \\
&= k\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi G(x)\sin(kx) \,dx \\
&= k b_k
\end{align*}

Since $G$ and $G'$ are both continuous and $2\pi$-periodic, we can now use
Parseval's formula to conclude the proof :
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi g(x)^2 \,dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi G(x)^2 \,dx \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2 \\
&\le \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 b_k^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi G'(x)^2 \,dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi g'(x)^2 \,dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Just to add that G is continuous in $[- \pi, \pi]$ since $g(0) = g( \pi) $ . Then the differentiated series is automatically the Fourier series of $G '$ . [On account of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the constant term of the Fourier series of G' is 0 bec of  $g(0) = g( \pi)$ by integrating $G'$ and use FTC.]  You have essentially proved this.

Comment: This result holds for general $g$ if  $g(0) = g( \pi) $, $g$ is absolutely continuous (so we have the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) and $g'$ is square integrable. [If g is smooth, then it is absolutely continuous  and $g'$ is integrable and square integrable . ] The proof is exactly as you have indicated

Comment: I missed out that g must also satisfied g(0) = 0 so that the extension of g to G is continuous in $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: When we have to show with the Parseval's formula an inequality in which case do we have to take an expansion of the function that is involved at the inequality?? @Math536

Comment: When we have to show with the Parseval's formula an inequality in which case do we have to take an expansion of the function that is involved at the inequality?? @Benjamin

Comment: @Mary Star  If you invoke Parseval Theorem, then there is no need to derive the identity. But you may have to show how to get the Fourier coefficients of $G '$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients of $G$.  This was shown above.  I will give a detail reply as answer.